# C# How to change background of workspace a RadTreeView in the part where there isn´t nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radtreeview

My `RadTreeView` is `Dock Fill` in a `Panel`, when paint the nodes is a part without nodes, that part I have not been able to change color [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJYba.png)

I tried with

```
RadTV_Menu_Principal.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
```

and

```
RadTV_Menu_Principal.RootElement.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
```

but no change. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Me.RadTreeView1.TreeViewElement.BackColor = Color.White
Me.RadTreeView1.TreeViewElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid
```

Try like this for me work.